# Avoiding script injection in input fields

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

To avoid script injection via the input fields, I'm setting the `ValidateInputAttribute` to false in my controller actions. And in my views, I'm using the `<%:` instead of `<%=`.

What I want to know, is there a more generic way in addition to above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> To avoid script injection via the input fields, I'm setting the
>   ValidateInputAttribute to false

This has exactly the contrary effect of what you are trying to achieve. It allows script injection. When you set it to false basically you disable the validation of request values.

> And in my views, I'm using the <%: instead of <%=

That's the correct way to HTML encode all data when displayed on a view. Of course if you are using HTML helpers (such as Html.DisplayFor or Html.EditorFor you don't need to use `<%:` because those helpers already take care of properly encoding the output).

Comment: But if you set the ValidateInputAttribute to true, then you will get the exception: A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client. And that is, what i dont want to. I just want to prevent to execute the potentialy scripts

Comment: Yes, that's normal. ASP.NET explicitly doesn't allow for such characters to be posted because they could be used for XSS injection. Of course if you properly HTML encode the output you are safe to disable this validation.

Comment: Thank you, but is this the right way, what i'm doing? now i have hundreds of views, where i have to replace the <%= with <%: . Is there a another way to do this more generic?